# How to edit a Form in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux. I've learned React and trying to learn Redux. I am building a todo app with Redux. I am managed to create, read and delete todos, but I am not managed to edit the todo.

My code: AddTodoForm

```
<FormGroup>
  <Label for="title">Title</Label>
  <Input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter Title" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /> {/* <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this, 'title')} /> */}
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup>
  <Label for="description">Description </Label>
  <Input type="textarea" name="description" id="description" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup>
  <div>
    <CustomInput className="toggleInput" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="exampleCustomCheckbox" label="Do You want to add Reminder??" onChange={this.toggle.bind(this, !this.state.checkBoxToggle)} />
  </div>
</FormGroup>
{this.state.checkBoxToggle ?
<FormGroup>
  <Label for="reminder">Reminder </Label>
  <Input type="datetime-local" name="date" defaultValue={moment(Date.now()).format( 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm')} id="date" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
</FormGroup>
: ''}
<FormGroup check row>
  <Col className="text-center">
  <Button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>Submit</Button>
  </Col>
</FormGroup>
```

My `handleChange` function, where I set states of input:

```
handleChange(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value, e.target.name);
  if (e.target.name == "date") {
    console.log('date is', e.target.value, new Date(e.target.value).valueOf());
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: new Date(e.target.value).valueOf()
    })
  } else {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
}
```

This the **render list function**, where I want to edit my todo, but I am not able to edit the todo. I am able to delete, but not edit:

```
renderList() {
  if (this.props.todos) {
    return _.map(this.props.todos, (todo, id) => {
      return (
        <tr key={id + 1}>
          <th scope="row">{id + 1}</th>
          <td><Input type="text" disabled name="title" id="title" value={todo.title} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /></td>
          <td><Input type="textarea" value={todo.description ? todo.description : this.state.description} name="description" id="description" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} /></td>
          <td>{todo.reminder}</td>
          <td> <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(this, todo._id)}>Delete</button></td>
          <td><button className='btn btn-success' onClick={this.markCompleted.bind(this, todo._id)}>Mark Complete</button></td>
        </tr>
      );
    })
  }
}
```

The specific todo, which I want to edit doesn't allow to type any value in the input box. I am not able to set it. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Instead of trying to reimplement form state, with event handlers, slice and reducers, use [Redux Form](https://redux-form.com/).

It is made for that specific purpose and has an elegant, efficient API.